# Duplicate item record display in table

Tags: php

in my code below I am trying to display the Item that is near to the ReOrder-Point or insufficient Items.
all ReOrder-Point are plus 5. 
in book Item it should be 6+5=11 it should be in the list
in pencil Item it should be 5+5=10 since it has more quantity it doesn't belong in list of insufficient Items

sample table Item:

`|  ID  |  Item name  |  Quantity   |  ReOrder-Point  |`
`|  1   |   book      |        11   |        6|`
`|  2   |   pencil    |        25   |        5|`
`|  3   |   shoe      |        4    |        5|`
`|  4   |   watch     |        20   |       10|`

```
    <?php
     include("connection/mysqlconnect.php");
     $sql="SELECT * FROM items";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $Item_Name = $row ['Item_Name'];
       $Stock_No = $row ['Stock_No'];
       $Description = $row ['Description'];
       $Quantity = $row ['Quantity'];
       $ReOrder_Point = $row ['ReOrder_Point'];

     $false_ReOrderP = $ReOrder_Point + 5;

      if ($Quantity <= $false_ReOrderP) {
        $rItem_Name = $Item_Name;
        $rStock_No = $Stock_No;
        $rDescription = $Description;
        $rQuantity = $Quantity;
        $rReOrder_Point = $ReOrder_Point;
     } else { 
           //nothing
      }
     ?>
```

this is what it displays. it duplicates depends on how many rows i have in my Items table
`|  ID  |  Item name  |  Quantity   |  ReOrder-Point  |`
`|  1   |   book      |        11   |        6|`
`|  1   |   book      |        11   |        6|`
`|  3   |   shoe      |        4    |        5|`
`|  3   |   shoe      |        4    |        5|`

expected table result should this
`|  ID  |  Item name  |  Quantity   |  ReOrder-Point  |`
`|  1   |   book      |        11   |        6|`
`|  3   |   shoe      |        4    |        5|`

I solved my problem with this. 
if anyone has the same query condition I have, feel free to analize :)
`$sql1="SELECT * FROM items WHERE Quantity <= (ReOrder_Point + 5)"`

Comment: Use `group by Item name` in your query or by `ID`

Comment: @Baracuda078 some of my Items have 6 or more duplicates after I use group by the duplicates reduce to 2 duplicates in all items and it give me 3 blank rows at the top.

Comment: in my current database I have 10items, and it display 10rows with 3blank at top with 2 items duplicated twice.